# Batch file to check, recheck and start if not running said .exe endlessly

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I would like to use batch file to check if a .exe is running and if it is, set a ping for say 30 seconds and recheck endlessly. If the .exe is not running then start another .bat file and then check again on a constant loop with out user action needed.

I have checked many pages here and tried many things and cant seam to get anything to work. so ill give more details.

I need this .bat file once started to check in see if "7dtd.exe" is running, if it is running then wait, i have see the whole ping null thing as a timer for about 30 seconds, and then recheck if "7dtd.exe" is running. if it is not running then i need it to start a separate "startdedi.bat" file and then check for the same "7dtd.exe" and continue to check endlessly. Any help would be great!

startdedicated.bat

```
@echo off
rem Starts a dedicated server
rem
rem -quit, -batchmode, -nographics: Unity commands
rem -configfile           : Allows server settings to be set up in an xml config file. Use no path if in same dir or full path.
rem -dedicated                    : Has to be the last option to start the dedicated server.

set LOGTIMESTAMP=


:: --------------------------------------------
:: REMOVE OLD LOGS (only keep latest 20)

for /f "tokens=* skip=19" %%F in ('dir 7DaysToDieServer_Data\output_log*.txt /o-d /tc /b') do del 7DaysToDieServer_Data\%%F



:: --------------------------------------------
:: BUILDING TIMESTAMP FOR LOGFILE

:: Check WMIC is available
WMIC.EXE Alias /? >NUL 2>&1 || GOTO s_start

:: Use WMIC to retrieve date and time
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%G IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
    IF "%%~L"=="" goto s_done
    Set _yyyy=%%L
    Set _mm=00%%J
    Set _dd=00%%G
    Set _hour=00%%H
    Set _minute=00%%I
    Set _second=00%%K
)
:s_done

:: Pad digits with leading zeros
Set _mm=%_mm:~-2%
Set _dd=%_dd:~-2%
Set _hour=%_hour:~-2%
Set _minute=%_minute:~-2%
Set _second=%_second:~-2%

Set LOGTIMESTAMP=__%_yyyy%-%_mm%-%_dd%__%_hour%-%_minute%-%_second%

:s_start


:: --------------------------------------------
:: STARTING SERVER


echo|set /p="251570" > steam_appid.txt

start 7daystodieserver -logfile 7DaysToDieServer_Data\output_log%LOGTIMESTAMP%.txt -quit -batchmode -nographics -configfile=serverconfig.xml -dedicated


echo Starting server ...
timeout 15

cls

echo.
echo Server running in background, you can close this window.
echo You can check the task manager if the server process is really running.
echo.
echo.

pause
```

I tried this command out and it seams to be working the way i need it to

```
@echo off
cls
:start
@echo Starting 7DTD Dedicated Test Server...

7daystodieserver -logfile 7DaysToDieServer_Data\output_log%LOGTIMESTAMP%.txt -quit -batchmode -nographics -

configfile=serverconfig.xml -dedicated

echo.
for /F "tokens=2" %%i in ('date /t') do set mydate=%%i
set mytime=%time%
echo Restarting Test Server: %mydate%:%mytime%
echo.
goto start
```

as long as the command windows stays up when the server closes it restarts it and lets me know the time when the server closed. thanks again for everyone help, this was driving me crazy!!!

Comment: You say you can't get it working... but what have you tried? We're not here to write your code for you, only to answer a specific question you have about your code. Please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What does `startdedi.bat` do? Does it just start `7dtd.exe`? What is it's content?

Comment: Please add that content and any accompanying information to your original question by using the **edit** facility.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Regejok has got the tasklist command wrong and also the conditional commands the wrong way around.

Try this:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
:LOOP
TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq 7dtd.exe"|FIND "==">NUL&&(TIMEOUT 30 /NOBREAK>NUL
)||CALL startdedi.bat
GOTO LOOP
```

Comment: @ECHO OFF
:LOOP
TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq 7dtd.exe"|FIND "==">NUL&&(TIMEOUT 30 /NOBREAK>NUL
)||CALL startdedi.bat
GOTO LOOP

with this if the .exe is not running, is it going to wait 30 seconds before starting?

Comment: This isn't a one sided interaction, you haven't answered my question from three hours earlier...

Comment: Sorry new to this site and didnt see the comment area, Yes the startdedi.bat starts the exe with conditions 

@echo off
rem Starts a dedicated server
rem
rem -quit, -batchmode, -nographics: Unity commands
rem -configfile    
rem -dedicated                    : Has to be the last option to start the dedicated server.
:: STARTING SERVER

Echo|set /p="251570" > steam_appid.txt

start 7daystodieserver -logfile 7DaysToDieServer_Data\output_log%LOGTIMESTAMP%.txt -quit -batchmode -nographics -configfile=serverconfig.xml -dedicated

echo Starting server ...
timeout 15

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be ping to wait? Use `timeout` instead.

This script will

- Check whether 7dtd.exe is running
- If not found, start startdedi.bat and end
- if found, wait 30 seconds and start over

---

```
:a
tasklist|findstr "7dtd.exe"||startdedi.bat
timeout 30
goto a
```

Second line lists all tasks, pipes output into `findstr` and upon 'failure', i.e. not finding a match, starts the second .bat (I realise there's the `/fi` parameter, but that doesn't set errorlevel).

If you insist on using `ping` for whatever reason:

```
ping -n 31 localhost
```

Comment: The logic is reversed, if the exe is **not** running, start the bat, so change `&&` to `||`. And as it is a batch use call otherwise the current batch is terminated.

Comment: is there anyway to keep the batch running and not end?

Comment: @BradleyKenny Just use `call startdedi.bat`

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research and digging more into the startdedi.bat file i tried this code and it seams to be working perfectly now. Thanks again for all the help and advice! this community is great!

```
@echo off
cls
:start
@echo Starting 7DTD Dedicated Test Server...

@echo off
rem Starts a dedicated server
rem
rem -quit, -batchmode, -nographics: Unity commands
rem -configfile           : Allows server settings to be set up in an xml config file. Use no path if in same dir or full path.
rem -dedicated                    : Has to be the last option to start the dedicated server.

set LOGTIMESTAMP=


:: --------------------------------------------
:: REMOVE OLD LOGS (only keep latest 20)

for /f "tokens=* skip=19" %%F in ('dir 7DaysToDieServer_Data\output_log*.txt /o-d /tc /b') do del 7DaysToDieServer_Data\%%F



:: --------------------------------------------
:: BUILDING TIMESTAMP FOR LOGFILE

:: Check WMIC is available
WMIC.EXE Alias /? >NUL 2>&1 || GOTO s_start

:: Use WMIC to retrieve date and time
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%G IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
    IF "%%~L"=="" goto s_done
    Set _yyyy=%%L
    Set _mm=00%%J
    Set _dd=00%%G
    Set _hour=00%%H
    Set _minute=00%%I
    Set _second=00%%K
)
:s_done

:: Pad digits with leading zeros
Set _mm=%_mm:~-2%
Set _dd=%_dd:~-2%
Set _hour=%_hour:~-2%
Set _minute=%_minute:~-2%
Set _second=%_second:~-2%

Set LOGTIMESTAMP=__%_yyyy%-%_mm%-%_dd%__%_hour%-%_minute%-%_second%

:s_start

7daystodieserver -logfile 7DaysToDieServer_Data\output_log%LOGTIMESTAMP%.txt -quit -batchmode -nographics -configfile=serverconfig.xml -dedicated

echo.
for /F "tokens=2" %%i in ('date /t') do set mydate=%%i
set mytime=%time%
echo Test Server was shutdown: %mydate%:%mytime%
echo.
goto start
```